# using xpath on non-hierarchical input

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am using SimpleXML and xpath in PHP to read xml files.  The problem is that the files (not of my own design) are not really hierarchical.  For example:

```
<country>USA</country>
...
...
<city>Los Angeles</city>
<city>San Diego</city>
...
...
<country>Canada</country>
...
...
<city>Toronto</city>
<city>Banff</city>
...
...
<country>Scotland</country>
...
...
<city>Glasgow</city>
<city>Edinburgh</city>
<city>Banff</city>
```

The ... represent arbitrary amounts of other fields.
I can read the file with $xml = simplexml_load_file( 'filename' );
My problem is finding the `<country>` corresponding to each `$xml->xpath("//city")`

That is, I'd like to know how to address the country which last occurred in the xml data for each city

Comment: Before processing such data, it's worth doing an XSLT transformation to turn it into a better-structured XML format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two viewpoints to approach this. One is to iterate all `city` elements and find the `country` sibling preceding it.

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$cities = [];
foreach ($data->xpath('//city') as $city) {
    $country = (string)($city->xpath('preceding-sibling::country')[0] ?? '');
    $cities[] = $city.', '.$country; 
}
var_dump($cities);
```

The other would be to iterate all `country` and `city` elements at the same time an store the current `country`.

```
$data = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$country = '';
$cities = [];
foreach ($data->xpath('//*[self::country or self::city]') as $node) {
    if ($node->getName() == 'country') {
        $country = (string)$node; 
    } else {
        $cities[] = $node.', '.$country; 
    }
}
var_dump($cities);
```

This would avoid executing the second Xpath expression for each `city` element.

For DOM users, this would not look much different. First using the secondary expression:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$cities = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//city') as $city) {
    $country = $xpath->evaluate('string(preceding-sibling::country)', $city);
    $cities[] = $city->textContent.', '.$country; 
}
var_dump($cities);
```

Storing the current country:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$country = '';
$cities = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//*[self::country or self::city]') as $node) {
    if ($node->localName == 'country') {
        $country = $node->textContent; 
    } else {
       $cities[] = $node->textContent.', '.$country; 
    }
}
var_dump($cities);
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, xpath 2.0 isn't supported by simplexml, so to implement @Birei's suggestion you'll have to go the long way around:

```
$cities = $xml->xpath("//city");
foreach ($cities as $city) {
   $country =  $city[0]->xpath('./preceding-sibling::country[1]');
   echo trim($city) . ' ' . trim($country[0]);
   echo "\r\n";
}
```

and you should get the same output.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `php` but there is a `xpath 2.0` expression that can find them:

Assuming a fixed input file, like:

```
<root>
<country>USA</country>
<city>Los Angeles</city>
<city>San Diego</city>
<country>Canada</country>
<city>Toronto</city>
<city>Banff</city>
<country>Scotland</country>
<city>Glasgow</city>
<city>Edinburgh</city>
<city>Banff</city>
</root>
```

The `xpath 2.0` expression:

```
for $x in //city return concat($x, ', ', $x/preceding-sibling::country[1])
```

yields:

```
'Los Angeles, USA'
'San Diego, USA'
'Toronto, Canada'
'Banff, Canada'
'Glasgow, Scotland'
'Edinburgh, Scotland'
'Banff, Scotland'
```

Comment: awesome thank you, I will most certainly give that a try.